# HTML web page displays fine in desktop and tablet but not mobile phone

Tags: html, css, mobile

Newbie to HTML here. Developed a web site in HTML and CSS which have now published. Seems to render fine on desktop and tablet (IPad) but not so on mobile. Have followed various suggestions particularly around viewport to resolve this without success. So now asking for help from those more knowledgeable.

**UPDATE**
The issue when displaying on mobile is that the navigation menu items are not listed.

The site can be viewed at http://speech4all.co.nz

I have listed the HTML for the index.html page and also the CSS below.

Thanks for your suggestions in advance

**Index.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!--[if IE 6]><![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="EN-GB"/>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="language" content="EN"/>
    <title>Speech4All - Speech and Language Therapy</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Speech4All"/>
    <link rel="author" title="Speech4All"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Speech and Language Therapy Services in Auckland"/>
    <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright © 2016 Speech4All, All Rights Reserved"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Speech4All - Speech and Language Therapy, Auckland"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:url" content="index.html"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Speech and Language Therapy Services in Auckland"/>
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Speech4All"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow,noodp,noydir"/>
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge;chrome=1"/>
    <link rel="canonical" href="index.html"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" type="text/css" id="google-fonts-css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amaranth:400,700"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" type="text/css" href="http://cdn-static.airsquare.com/5.6.4/compiled/theme/css.cfm?name=balloon&amp;grid_max_width=960"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" type="text/css" id="managed-css" href="asset/csss4a.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>        
</head>
<body>        
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header">
            <div class="container_12">
                <div class="grid_12">
                    <div class="branding" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
                        <a href="index.html" itemprop="url">
                            <img background-color="#add8e6" width="300" height="200" itemprop="logo" src="blah.png" alt="Speech4All" />
                        </a>
                    </div>                        
                    <div>
                        <a href="mailto:info@speech4all.co.nz?Subject=Website%20Enquiry" target="_top">info@speech4all.co.nz</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="main-navigation">
                        <ul>                                
                            <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
                            <li><a href="faqs.html">FAQs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>                            
                            <li><a href="testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>           
    <div id="content">
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div class="container_12">
            <div class="grid_4">                
                <h3>About me</h3>
                <p>My name is Anony Mouse and I am the Speech and Language Therapist for Speech4All in the Central Auckland Area. </p>
                <p>I specialise in working with children, adolescents and adults with speech and/or language delays and disorders.</p>                    
                <p style="text-align: center;">&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;
                    <img alt="" height="386" src="./images/Blah.jpg" width="640" />
                </p>                        
             </div>
            <div class="grid_4">                
                <h3>Qualifications</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Master of Science with First Class Honours in Speech Language Sciences</li>                        
                </ul>
                <h3>&#160;</h3>
             </div>
            <div class="grid_4">                   
                <h3>Why choose me?</h3>
                <p>I pride myself on providing individualised client based Speech Language Therapy. I am passionate about what I do to support the communication needs of others and believe that everyone is capable of making progress. </p>                    
             </div>
            <div class="grid_4">
                 <h3>What&#160;I offer</h3>
                     <h4>Speech and Language Therapy Services</h4>
                     <ul>
                         <li>FREE consultation including a 15 minute screening to determine if Speech Language Therapy is required and would be beneficial.</li>                             
                     </ul>                         
                </div>
         </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
    body { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }


h1, h2, h3, h4 { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }


#header .branding h1 { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }


#header .main-navigation ul li a { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }
.ui-tooltip-main-navigation-sub-menu .ui-tooltip-content { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }


.button { font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }



body { background-color: #FFFFFF; } 



#wrapper { box-shadow: 0px 0px 30px #283036; }


#content { background:#FFFFFF; } 


#header { background:#add8e6; }


#header .branding h1 a { color:#FFFFFF; }


#header .main-navigation ul li a { color: #5A1C2E; text-decoration: none;}


@media only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) 
{
    td#main_box 
    {
        -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -moz-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;
    }   
}


#header .main-navigation ul li a:hover { color:#8F1728; }


.ui-tooltip-main-navigation-sub-menu .ui-tooltip-content ul li a { color:#283036; }


.ui-tooltip-main-navigation-sub-menu .ui-tooltip-content { background:#FFFFFF; }


.ui-tooltip-main-navigation-sub-menu .ui-tooltip-content ul li a:hover { background:#8F1728; }


.ui-tooltip-main-navigation-sub-menu .ui-tooltip-content ul li a:hover { color:#FFFFFF; }


body { color:#555555; }
.cart table th { color:#555555; }


h1, h2, h3, h4 { color:#333333; }
.product h1 a { color:#333333; }


a { color:#8F1728; }    

a:hover { color:#283036; }
.twitter-panel-listing { background:#F3F3F3; }
.testimonial-panel-listing { background:#F3F3F3; }
.testimonial-listing { background:#F3F3F3; }


.button { background:#add8e6; }


.button { color:#000000; }
.button:hover { color:#000000; }


th { background: #8F1728; }


th { color: #FFFFFF; }


#footer { background:#E7E7E7; }
```

Comment: What, exactly, isn't working on mobile? I tested in mobile view in Firefox (OSX) and the page seems fine? I also loaded it on my Android (Android 6.x) Chrome, and it seems to be working fine there as well? What, exactly, isn't working?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I cannot view the menu items in the header in mobile.

Answer (score 0):

The site looks OK to me on mobile, except your navigation isn't displaying. If that's the issue, it's because of this CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 0px)
.main-navigation li:not(.toggle) {
    display: none;
}
```

I don't see a `.toggle` in your code, so I presume you just want to remove that CSS and your navigation will be visible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Plea bear with me if the following seems a little dim but I cannot see any lines reading media only screen and (Max-width: 767px etc) I do have a line reading media only screen and (Max-width: 480px) etc in the css which I inserted when I found the site did not render well on iPad. Are you saying I need to insert the media joy code that you indicated in your answer?

Comment: It's in [this css file](https://cdn-static.airsquare.com/5.6.4/compiled/theme/css.cfm?name=balloon&grid_max_width=960) line 837.